# Setting null for single-valued navigation property using Xrm.WebApi

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-webapi, dynamics-crm-365-v9

We are in the process of remediation, re-engineering old JS web resources for latest D365 v9 sdk changes w.r.t Client scripting API improvements & deprecation.

When rewriting the web api methods using `Xrm.WebApi`, we end up with this blocker.

The scenario is setting `null` to lookup, and tried the below code:

```
var data = {
    "abc_relatedentity@odata.bind": null
};

Xrm.WebApi.updateRecord("abc_entity", abc_entityid, data).then(successCallback, errorCallback);
```

This is throwing error:

> "The 'odata.bind' instance or property annotation has a null value. In OData, the 'odata.bind' instance or property annotation must have a non-null string value."

The idea is to retire the below redundant XHR request code. But this is the only workaround we have now (referring [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/webapi/associate-disassociate-entities-using-web-api#remove-a-reference-to-an-entity)).

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("DELETE", Xrm.Utility.getGlobalContext().getClientUrl() + "/api/data/v9.0/accounts(recordGUID)/account_parent_account/$ref", true);
req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
req.setRequestHeader("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
req.setRequestHeader("OData-Version", "4.0");
req.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState === 4) {
        req.onreadystatechange = null;
        if (this.status === 204 || this.status === 1223) {
            //Success - No Return Data - Do Something
        } 
    }
};
req.send();
```

Anybody faced this & handled it? Am I missing something?

Comment: I am also facing the similar issue. How did you get it fixed?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use Delete method to remove the lookup value 
format is as follows: 
/api/data/v8.0/accounts(1DD18913-11CB-E511-80D2-C4346BDC11C1)/primarycontactid/$ref

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/webapi/associate-disassociate-entities-using-web-api#remove-a-reference-to-an-entity

Comment: @JimDaly-MSFT- this is the exact one we are using now ie DELETE verb in XMLHttpRequest (I have added in question itself). I’m looking for Xrm.Webapi version actually

Comment: Xrm.WebApi does what it does, but it doesn't include everything you can do.
You can still use XmlHttpRequest without the limitations of Xrm.WebApi.

See the JavaScript samples using Sdk.request here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/webapi/web-api-samples-client-side-javascript

You will find a lot of samples using it nearby.

Comment: @JimDaly-MSFT- Ok then I’ll wait for future updates of Xrm.WebApi if any development in this scenario, till then I’ll use the same what I'm doing right now.

Answer (score 1):

I think set the column to null is enough, please make sure you removed '@odata.bind'

var data = {
"abc_relatedentity": null
};

This is working for me.

Comment: Yeah, probably latest development in Dynamics web api allows this

Answer (score 0):

you should try Xrm.WebApi.online.execute or Xrm.WebApi.online.executeMultiple

```
var Sdk = window.Sdk || {};


/**
 * Request to execute an update operation
 */
Sdk.UpdateRequest = function(entityName, entityId, payload) {
    this.etn = entityName;
    this.id = entityId;
    this.payload = payload;
};

// NOTE: The getMetadata property should be attached to the function prototype instead of the
// function object itself.
Sdk.UpdateRequest.prototype.getMetadata = function () {
    return {
        boundParameter: null,
        parameterTypes: {},
        operationType: 2, // This is a CRUD operation. Use '0' for actions and '1' for functions
        operationName: "Update",
    };
};

// Construct a request object from the metadata
var payload = {
    "_abc_relatedentity_value": null 
};
var updateRequest = new Sdk.UpdateRequest("abc_entity", abc_entityid, payload);

// Use the request object to execute the function
Xrm.WebApi.online.execute(updateRequest).then(
    function (response) {
       console.log(response)
    },
    function(error) {
        console.log(error.message);
        // handle error conditions
    }
);
```

Answer (score -1):

Great news! You can set lookup field to `null` in `PATCH` request by adding this header to your request.

```
autodisassociate: true
```

And then you can use something like this to alter your lookup field in any way:

```cs
SetLookupField(requestBody, "systemusers", "msdfm_MyUser", null)
// Or
SetLookupField(requestBody, "systemusers", "msdfm_MyUser", "f5b0b514-aea8-ea11-a812-000d3a569fe1")

// ...

private static void SetLookupField(JObject requestBody, string typePlural, string name, string value)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
    {
        requestBody.Add($"{name}@odata.bind", $"/{typePlural}({value})");
    }
    else
    {
        requestBody.Add($"_{name.ToLower()}_value", null);
    }
}
```

OP uses `XMLHttpRequest` anyway, so I thought, a way to do this using `PATCH` will be relevant here.

Comment: Good to know, thanks for your answer. My original ask is to retire XHR and move to Xrm.WebApi, it’s still pending.

Comment: Use of this autodisassociate header is not documented or supported.

Answer (score -2):

To set null on the lookup use:

```
var data = { _[LookupFieldName]_value : null } 
Xrm.WebApi.updateRecord("abc_entity", abc_entityid, data).then(successCallback, errorCallback
```

For example to remove `contact.parentcustomerid` field value you need to use:

```
var data = {};
data._parentcustomerid_value = null
var t = await Xrm.WebApi.updateRecord("contact", "{0200E6F5-1D21-E811-A954-0022480042B3}", data)
```

Comment: In fact, this still fail with error "Property _abc_relatedentity_value cannot be updated to null. The reference property can only be deleted."

Answer (score -2):

I just tried in v9.1.0.3832
`var data = { _[LookupFieldName]_value : null }` is working for me.

```
var data =
{
  "statecode": 1,
  "*_myprefix_mylookupfieldname_value*": null
}
Xrm.WebApi.updateRecord("*entityName*", *recordId*, data);
```

Comment: I just tested in 1710 (9.1.0.4416) & getting the same error "Property _abc_relatedentity_value cannot be updated to null. The reference property can only be deleted."

Comment: _[LookupFieldName]_value fields are read-only calculated fields

Comment: @JimDaly-MSFT- thanks Jim, do you know why some people keep saying it is working then - https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/microsoft-dynamics-crm-forum/310854/update-null-to-lookup-field-using-xrm-webapi-updaterecord/1093357#1093357

Comment: It probably depends on whether you are using the client-side Xrm.WebApi methods or using the Web API directly. The client API is probably using the autodisassociate header mentioned by others. This is not a supported header. It works, but is not supported. We are working on providing a supported option. When remove it, there will be no notification. So use at your own risk - or just depend on the Xrm.WebAPI methods.