# Unable to remove Dynamics 365 Appointment's regardingobjectid value using Web API

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-365, appointment, dynamics-crm-webapi

I'm trying to remove value of field `regardingobjectid` from a appointment entity using Microsoft Dynamics 365 Web API. Not able to but it shows the below error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "",
    "message": "The property 'regardingobjectid' does not exist on type 'Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.appointment'. Make sure to only use property names that are defined by the type."
```

**Request**

```
PATCH https://XXXXXXX.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v8.2/appointments(9de8ba18-8303-e911-8147-3863bb2eb450)
```

**Headers:**

```
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer *Token*
```

**Body:**

```
{
  "subject": "Check Updates",
  "ownerid@odata.bind": "/systemusers(51d09106-22b6-e811-8143-3863bb2ec140)",
  "createdby@odata.bind": "/systemusers(51d09106-22b6-e811-8143-3863bb2ec140)",
  "location": "",
  "description": "nuldasddsadsal",
  "statecode": 3,
  "scheduledstart": "2018-12-19T06:45:00Z",
  "scheduledend": "2018-12-19T07:15:00Z",
  "isalldayevent": false,
  "regardingobjectid": null,
  "activitypointer_activity_parties": [
    {
      "partyid_account@odata.bind": "/accounts(4a2612e2-664b-e411-93ff-0050569469bd)",
      "participationtypemask": "6"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of things:

1.To update/overwrite a lookup field value using web api, we have to use single-valued navigation property `regardingobjectid_account@odata.bind`

```
var entity = {};
entity["regardingobjectid_account@odata.bind"] = "/accounts(1F496057-8DE7-E811-A97A-000D3A1A9EFB)";

var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("PATCH", Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + "/api/data/v8.2/appointments(6D78AD2C-5A16-E811-A955-000D3A1A9407)", true);
req.setRequestHeader("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
req.setRequestHeader("OData-Version", "4.0");
req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
req.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState === 4) {
        req.onreadystatechange = null;
        if (this.status === 204) {
            //Success - No Return Data - Do Something
        } else {
            Xrm.Utility.alertDialog(this.statusText);
        }
    }
};
req.send(JSON.stringify(entity));
```

2.As said above `PATCH` is for updating value of all field types, except for removing lookup value (updating `null` in lookup) - we have to use `DELETE`

[My SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49329838/7920473) and [Community blog post](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/crminogic/archive/2016/04/15/how-to-delete-record-field-value-using-the-web-api-in-dynamics-crm)

Comment: After some Research Request *DELETE*: **https://XXXXXXX.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v8.2/appointments(EE4C7268-81B7-E811-8143-3863BB368D98)/_regardingobjectid_value** works well for me for removing regardingobjectid